# Access the content of a template inside the component class in Angular

Tags: angular

If we have component A (child component) that takes this input:

@Input() template1?: TemplateRef;

In the parent component we pass that input like this:
<component-A [template1]="tmpl">

```
<ng-template #tmpl>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</ng-template>
```

The question is:
Can we access the content of the template (h1 in this example) from inside the child component (component A) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **`ViewContainerRef`**, here's an example:

```
export class ChildComp {
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    const _injector = this.viewContainerRef.parentInjector;
    const _parent: ParentComponent = _injector.get<ParentComponent>(ParentComponent);  
    this._parent.property = 'some value';
  }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: parentInjector property is deprecated.